# Fetch changed form field value from a dynamic modal window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic modal window with a form. when i update the form fields and click on update button, i am unable to get the changed values in js but it gives me the original values.

How do get the changed values instead of original form vlaue.

in PHP i formed the content of the modal window and returned it to ajax to populate the content in modal:

```
$content="
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
            <h4 class='modal-title' id='formModalLabel'>Edit Banner</h4>
        </div>
        <form class='form-horizontal' role='form'>
            <div class='modal-body'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <label for='title' class='control-label'>Title</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm-9'>
                        <input type='text' name='title' id='title' class='form-control' placeholder='title' value='$title'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <label for='alt' class='control-label'>Alternate</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm-9'>
                        <input type='text' name='alt' id='alt' class='form-control' placeholder='alt' value='$alt'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <label for='url' class='control-label'>Image URL</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm-9'>
                        <input type='text' name='url' id='url' class='form-control' placeholder='url' value='$url'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <label for='link' class='control-label'>Link</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm-9'>
                        <input type='text' name='link' id='link' class='form-control' placeholder='link' value='$link'>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>
                <button type='button' id='$pid' class='btn btn-primary updatebtn'>Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        ";
echo $content;
```

JS code to populate the modal with the content

```
success: function(html)
            {
                $('.modal-content').show().html(html);              
                $("#formModal").modal("show");
            }
```

JS code on click of update button in modal window

```
$('.modal-content').delegate('.updatebtn', 'click', function() {
    var title =  $("#title").val(); // this gives original vlaues
});
```

Thanks

AJ

Comment: Please provide a minimal `DEMO` on how you are getting this `dynamic modal` and it will be easy for us to help you..

Comment: if this helps, i updated the code, pl help. thank you

Comment: Try using **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead of delegate. But the above code should work.

Comment: This is a **[common known issue](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-preserves-the-old-input-value-after-the-dialog-is-destroyed)** I guess with UI dialog.

Comment: @ShaunakD OP might be referring `twitter-bootstrap`'s `modal` not `jquery ui`.

Comment: `console.log($("#title").val())` and see what you are getting when the `modal` is open

Comment: this may be a cache problem

Comment: console.log($("#title").val()) returns the old values. i cleared the cache still it dosent return the changed values